# Swift build on Ubuntu: Handling whitespace in object file names

Tags: swift, linux, ubuntu, clang

I'm trying to build a swift app on Ubuntu 18.04. It's a [vapor](https://vapor.codes) app with the following `Package.swift`:

```
// swift-tools-version:4.0
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Project",
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", from: "3.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent-sqlite.git", from: "3.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor-community/vapor-ext.git", from: "0.3.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/attaswift/BigInt.git", from: "3.1.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "App", dependencies: ["FluentSQLite", "Vapor", "ServiceExt", "BigInt"]),
        .target(name: "Run", dependencies: ["App"]),
        .testTarget(name: "AppTests", dependencies: ["App"])
    ]
)
```

Now I'm calling `swift build`: Fetching packages works, compiling works, but linking results in many of the following error messages:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/home/ubuntu/project/.build/x86_64-unknown-linux/debug/BigInt.build/Words'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'and'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Bits.swift.o'
```

I'm using [this BigInt package](https://github.com/attaswift/BigInt) and unfortunately, it has some whitespaces in the file names, e.g. `Words and Bits.swift`. This results in the file `.build/x86_64-unknown-linux/debug/BigInt.build/Words and Bits.swift.o` but the swift compiler on Linux seems to not allow whitespaces in those filenames.

Now, I could fork the repository and change all the file names. But maybe there is another, easier solution to this problem?

*Extra confusion:* I tried to do the same in a docker container ([dockerfile](https://github.com/vapor-cloud/docker/blob/master/Swift/Vapor3/web.Dockerfile)) and it works... Seems that they are using clang-3.8 instead of the default clang-6, maybe this could be the problem?!

Comment: It doesn't look like any compiler is to blame here. Rather, the conpiler is not being called correctly. Please show your build commands.

Comment: Good point, I just added the build command, it's just `swift build`.

Comment: It is not terribly informative without the contents of your build file.

Comment: I must admit, I'm not 100% sure, what further information you're asking for. I added the Package.swift file but didn't dive deeper into the way those tools work.

Comment: I re-read your question. It looks like you are using a canned build file. I initially assumed that you wrote your own, and wanted you to show it. I actually have no idea how swift build works, but I'm 100% sure it is not about the version of clang. Any version would work with file names that contain spaces, it's just something that needs no special consideration. White space can cause problems in file names when they are passed through a shell. Build systems do that, clang doesn't.

Comment: Alright, I see. I'll look more specific into how swift build works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a direct solution, but a way to get it working. Maybe it'll help someone with the same problem:

Make sure to use Swift version 4.2.2 (and not e.g. 4.2.0). Somehow they obviously fixed this problem between those versions. ‍♂️